# Print out currency value in java using NumberFormat

Tags: java, currency-formatting

```
NumberFormat nf =NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CANADA);
    
System.out.println("Checking account balance = $"+String.format("%.2f", this.balance));
```

How to connect this two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the NumberFormat will be the responsible for formatting your balance, you don't need to format it using `String.format`.

So you could use something like that:

`System.out.println("Checking account balance = " + nf.format(balance));`

Just to highlight, I've removed also the `$` from the text, as the NumberFormat will handle that for you.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Use `nf.format(value)` to format the value as per locale needed.

```
 NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CANADA);
 String balance = nf.format(this.balance);
 System.out.println("Checking account balance = "+balance);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CANADA);
BigDecimal balance = BigDecimal.valueOf(12323);
System.out.println(String.format("Checking account balance = %s",numberFormat.format(balance)));
```

Comment: `Numberformat.format()` doesn't look like it takes `BigDecimal` as an arugment. Do you know how this works?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
String number = String.format("%.2f", this.balance);
NumberFormat nf =  NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.CANADA);
System.out.println("Checking account balance = "+ nf.format(Double.valueOf(number)));
```

The balance is formatted as you wish and then it is converted to the currency format